# 【Java -> C】C言語でJavaの「SecureRandom」は実現できるのか？

Tags: java, c, security

始めて質問させて頂きます。
質問は題名通りですが、概要を説明させて頂きます。

Javaの「SecureRandom」で生成した乱数を
暗号化した値で認証する処理が必要となり、

暗号を使って通信する相手はJavaのアプリ。
こちらはマイコン(C言語)となっています。

同じ言語で設計していれば悩む必要のない話ですが、
相手は既に設計完了済みで変更できず、かつこちらも
開発環境的にC以外では開発ができません。

とりあえず、Javaの「Java.security.SecureRandom」と
同じ乱数をCで実現可能なのか現在調査中ですが、
これといってヒントになるような資料が見当たりません。

恐れ入りますが、何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら
ご教授頂けると幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 同じ乱数アルゴリズムを使用しなければいけない理由は何でしょうか。

Comment: "Javaの「SecureRandom」で生成した乱数を暗号化した値で認証する処理""暗号を使って通信"そのために`SecureRandom`のクローンが必要、というのはいまいち理解しがたいので、そもそも要求されていることが間違っているか誤解があるような気がします。Javaで実装した場合のコードを見せられませんか。

Comment: h2so5様、suzukis様
コメント有難うございます。

h2so5様
>>同じ乱数アルゴリズムを使用しなければいけない理由は何でしょうか。
suzukis様
>>そもそも要求されていることが間違っているか誤解があるような気がします。

\\\ 質問時、私も少々困惑しており、冷静に考えてみると理由がわかりません。
客先に問い合わせて見ます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既に「暗号論的に安全な乱数」を送ってくる側があるのに
認証する側で「同じ乱数」が得られるはずも無いんですがどういう意味でしょうか？
(同じ乱数を得ることができるのなら暗号論的に安全ではない)

マイコン側で暗号論的に安全な乱数を生成する、のであれば
何らかのハードウエアが使えるはずなのでそれに頼るしかないです。
A/D 変換器の熱雑音とかが簡単です。
それなりの電気回路をあらかじめ盛り込んでおく必要がありますけど。

Comment: 御回答有難うございます。ハードウェアの検討も現在検討中です。

Answer (score 0):

Javaの内部実装を知りたいのであれば、[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/)のソースを参照してはいかがでしょうか。

言うまでもありませんが、コードを利用するのであればライセンスに注意してください。

Comment: 小生Javaは素人のため、そのようなものがあることを知りませんでした。
有難うございます。参考にさせて頂きます。